# Does ionic takes care of the 300ms delay in tabs

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm using the ionic/angular combo to build an mobile application. I've a tab control as shown below,

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-only tabs-balanced">

  <ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Users" icon="icon ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/users">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-users"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Account" icon="icon ion-gear-b" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

When I navigate between the tabs I notice a delay in Samsung Note I. Does ionic takes care of the 300ms delay? I also notice the delay when selecting an item in the ionic list which navigates to a different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic fixed the 300ms delay in all tap events - see [this blog post](http://ionicframework.com/blog/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/). Instead, what you're experiencing is a delay as the browser renders the new state.

Check out this [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1434) issue on Ionic to track the problem.